# Is it possible to use a custom type with the FSharp.Data.CsvProvider when specifying a Schema?

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data, fsharp.data.typeproviders

I'm working in F# with a CSV that looks like this:

```
When,Where,HowMuch
11/24/2019,Germany,100 EUR
11/25/2019,France,100 EUR
11/26/2019,Switzerland,50 CHF
11/27/2019,USA,75 USD
```

I'm using the [CSV Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) in the [FSharp.Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/) package to parse this data.

```
type CurrencyDetector = CsvProvider<"Currencies.csv">
```

Obviously the first column is a date, and the second is a string.

For the third, I'd *like* to use this type:

```
type Money (amountAndDenomination : string) =

    let parts = amountAndDenomination.Split ' '

    member __.Amount = Decimal.Parse parts.[0]
    member __.Denomination = parts.[1]
```

I've tried a few permutations of the `Schema` argument in my CsvProvider line, but nothing has worked so far.  For example:

```
type CurrencyDetector = CsvProvider<"Currencies.csv",Schema="When (date),Where (string),HowMuch (Money)">
```

`When` comes out as `DateTime` and `Where` as `string`, but `HowMuch` becomes a string property named `HowMuch (Money)`:

[image: Demonstration of type provider properties in use]

Is there a way to use my own classes with the CsvProvider, or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation for the CsvProvider](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html), I don't think it is possible:

`Schema` parameter: "Optional column types, in a comma separated list. **Valid types are** int, int64, bool, float, decimal, date, guid, string, int?, int64?, bool?, float?, decimal?, date?, guid?, int option, int64 option, bool option, float option, decimal option, date option, guid option and string option. **You can also specify a unit** and the name of the column like this: Name (**type<\unit>**), or you can override only the name. If you don't want to specify all the columns, you can reference the columns by name like this: ColumnName=type."

Note in the above, however, that there **is** the possibility of using [units of measure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure). So you might explore creating units of measure for the currency denominations. The type provider **might** require a different format for that column though.

In the [documentation for the CSV Type Provider](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html), you can find further information about units of measure and also how to "transform the columns themselves by using Map", which should enable you to map the `string` type to a custom type. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/296f0d560cb1624443aa260357f8eb5f942232e4/src/Csv/CsvGenerator.fs#L42), suggests that the `Rows` collection is a sequence of `Row` objects, each of which is a tuple. So you should be able to use `Seq.map` and/or any other function in the `Seq` module to post-process the generated collection.

Comment: CsvProvider documentation link is dead.